# Exponential of 4x4 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, matrix-decomposition

It is asked to calculate $e^{tA}$, where

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
 0&1  &  0&0 \\ 
 3\omega ^2&0   &0   &2 \omega \\ 
 0& 0  & 0 &1 \\ 
 0& -2 \omega  &0  &0 
\end{pmatrix}$$

First, I've tried to calculate $A^2$ and $A^3$ to see if it has a "known form" or if the matrix is nilpotent. It doesn't seen the case. Then, I've tried Jordan Decomposition of A , which looks like, for me, the best way of doing it. It has 2 imaginary eigenvalues $-i\omega, \; i\omega$ and two real $0$ with multiplicity 2. It gives me the answer (I mean, is not incorrect), but I am wondering if there is a better way of calculating this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What are $\omega$ and $a$?

Comment: it was not a, but $\omega$, sorry

Comment: Is $\omega$ an arbitrary real constant?

Comment: $\omega$ is an arbitrary positive real constant.

Comment: Also, did you notice that the Jordan form only has *one* block associated with the eigenvalue $0$ (in other words, the matrix is not diagonalizable)?

Comment: No, it is not. The 0 eigenvalue only has 1 l.i engenvector associated with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think computation via some kind of Jordan decomposition is pretty much the best you could do for calculation by hand.

I suspect that you might make things slightly easier if you used something like [Jordan real form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form#Real_matrices), if you're comfortable exponentiating rotation matrices.